# SQL Server Launchpad fail to start

Tags: sql-server, azure-machine-learning-service, launchpad

I want to use machine learning services in SQL Server database, and now I install machine learning services(In-database) and python successfully, but I cannot run python in SSMS, when I run:

````
>```SQL  
EXEC sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'Python',
@script=N'
OutputDataSet = InputDataSet;
',
@input_data_1 =N'SELECT 1 AS hello'
WITH RESULT SETS (([hello] int not null));
GO```
````

it displays the error as below:

```
>SQL Server was unable to communicate with the LaunchPad service. Please verify the configuration of 
the service.
```

So I need to start the SQL Server Launchpad in SQL Server Configuration Manager, but fail with the error messages:

```
>The request failed or the services did not respond in a timely fashion.Consult the event log or 
other applicable error logs for details.
```

I don't know where the error log is, but I have check the Event Viewer it just shown a similar info:

```
>The service did not respond in a timely fashion.
>A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the SQL Server Launchpad service to connect.
```

What I have try:
1. Restart the SQL Server multiple times.
2. Make sure the account "NT SERVICE\MSSQLLaunchpad$SQLEXPRESS" that log on Launchpad has the necessary permission:
- Adjust memory quotas for a process (SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege)
- Bypass traverse checking (SeChangeNotifyPrivilege)
- Log on as a service (SeServiceLogonRight)
- Replace a process-level token (SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege)
- Allow log on locally

My SQL Server Version is :

> SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU17) (KB4515579) - 14.0.3238.1 (X64)

Comment: I install machine learning service on a computer without a domain environment, and everything is running well. I think maybe the domain administrator has made some permission restrictions. But I have to install it in a domain environment.~.So,any clues?

Comment: I had the exact same problem; same SQL Server version. Doing a repair of the SQL instance through SQL Installation Center fixed it. I had another SQL Server named instance whose Launchpad service worked fine, but didn't work for the default instance. A repair of the default instance helped me get past the problem. It might help you too. I did compare permissions, etc. between the two SQL Server instances and didn't find anything different between the two setups. Not sure what the repair really did, but it fixed the issue somehow.